# extracting substrings with regex

Tags: awk

I have the following file:

```
> cat hit.txt | head
gene.69778.3.0.p1
gene.65186.0.2.p1
chr11_pilon3.g961.t1
gene.3169.3.4.p1
chr11_pilon3.g3568.t1
gene.1708.8.0.p1
gene.41465.0.3.p1
chr04_pilon3.g11582.t1
gene.101930.0.1.p1
gene.93918.0.0.p1
gene.65186.8.2.p1
```

and I would like to get this output:

```
gene.69778
gene.65186
gene.3169
gene.1708
gene.41465
gene.101930
gene.93918
gene.65186
```

I only could figure out `awk '$1 ~ /^gene/'`. How is possible to get the above output?

Comment: So much easier with `egrep`, use: `egrep -o '^gene\.[0-9]+' file > newfile`

Comment: @user3439894 Yes, I also had a POSIX BRE `grep` solution in my answer, just added a POSIX ERE, `grep -oE '^gene\.[0-9]+' hit.txt > results.txt`.

Comment: @user3439894 `egrep` is deprecated in favor of `grep -E`.

Comment: @Ed Morton, Just because it's depreciated doesn't mean it can't be used! I believe in KISS solutions and what I posted in my first comment is just that and it works!

Comment: @user3439894 You're right, deprecated doesn't mean it **can't** be used, it means it **shouldn't** be used because it's been replaced by something else and will probably be removed in the future. Continuing to use deprecated software is like continuing to save your music on cassette tapes. Feel free to ignore my comment, of course, but it's important for others reading this to be aware of.

Comment: @Ed Morton, RE "it means it shouldn't be used because it's been replaced by something else and will probably be removed in the future." -- That your opinion, which of course your are entitled to, but as long as it still available and can be easily used in a uses case scenario such as the OP there is absolutely nothing wrong with using it! I have to say that the logic you are using here is tantamount getting rig of ones older computer because a newer model came out this year.

Comment: @user3439894 no, that's not my opinion, that's the **definition** of the word `deprecated` as it applies to software. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation, https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deprecate, etc.. The logic I'm using is not similar to replacing your computer with a newer model, it's more like replacing your typewriter or word processor with a computer. Sounds like you find `egrep` better in some way than `grep -E` so feel free to keep using that if you like of course, it's entirely your choice, I was just giving you and others a heads up about it being deprecated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use this simple `sed`:

```sh
sed -nE 's/^(gene\.[0-9]+).*/\1/p' hit.txt

gene.69778
gene.65186
gene.3169
gene.1708
gene.41465
gene.101930
gene.93918
gene.65186
```

**How it works:**

- `-n`: Disable normal output
- `-E`: Enable extended regex
- `^(gene\.[0-9]+)`: Match `gene.<number>` at start and capture in group #1
- `.*`: Match remaining string
- `\1`: Back-reference to group #1
- `p`: Print substituted substring

---

Alternatively this `gnu awk` also does the job:

```sh
awk '/^gene\./ {print gensub(/^(gene\.[0-9]+).*/, "\\1", "1")}' hit.txt

gene.69778
gene.65186
gene.3169
gene.1708
gene.41465
gene.101930
gene.93918
gene.65186
```

Answer (score 3):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/^gene\.[^.]+/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' file
gene.69778
gene.65186
gene.3169
gene.1708
gene.41465
gene.101930
gene.93918
gene.65186
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
awk -F. '$1 == "gene"{print $1"."$2}'  hit.txt > results.txt
```

The field separator is set to a dot, if Field 1 equals `gene`, then the values in Field 1 and 2 are joined with a dot and printed.

See the [`awk` online demo](https://ideone.com/tWxFwW):

```sh
s='gene.69778.3.0.p1
gene.65186.0.2.p1
chr11_pilon3.g961.t1
gene.3169.3.4.p1
chr11_pilon3.g3568.t1
gene.1708.8.0.p1
gene.41465.0.3.p1
chr04_pilon3.g11582.t1
gene.101930.0.1.p1
gene.93918.0.0.p1
gene.65186.8.2.p1
'
awk -F. '$1 == "gene"{print $1"."$2}' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```sh
gene.69778
gene.65186
gene.3169
gene.1708
gene.41465
gene.101930
gene.93918
gene.65186
```

**Alternatively, just use `grep`**:

```sh
grep -o '^gene\.[0-9]\{1,\}' hit.txt > results.txt
grep -oE '^gene\.[0-9]+' hit.txt > results.txt
```

See [this `grep` demo](https://ideone.com/FDMLtv). Details:

- `^`  - start of string
- `gene\.` - `gene.`
- `[0-9]\{1,\}` - one or more digits.

Answer (score 0):

Also in GNU `awk` using `split()` function with the optional fourth argument to hold the text of the field separator.

```
awk  '$0 ~ /^gene/ {split($0,a,/\./,sep);print a[1]sep[1]a[2]}' file
gene.69778
gene.65186
gene.3169
gene.1708
gene.41465
gene.101930
gene.93918
gene.65186
```